# R: extracting characters around comma from character vector

Tags: r, vector

Let's have a character vector with one comma inside:

```
vector <- c("abcdefghi,jklmnopr")
```

How get vector with characters around the comma?

```
# expecter outcome
# "i,j"
```

And how do this for vector with multiple commas inside?

```
vector <- c("ab,cdefghi,jklm,nopr")
# expecter outcome
# "b,c", "i,j", "m,n"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `stringr` package:

```
stringr::str_extract_all(vector, ".,.")
# [[1]]
# [1] "b,c" "i,j" "m,n"
```